# How to fit references number into a single table

Tags: tables, citing, scaling

I am working on overleaf and preparing a report. I am working on a review paper in which I surveyed over a hundred papers. Thus, I need to put them as references. However, I am unable to fit the reference number in a single table. Please have a look at the attached images. I also share my code with the output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
%% for removing the footer 
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  %\let\@oddfoot\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{lineno} %% package for line number
%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{afterpage,lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum, pdflscape}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table}
%%\footnotesize\tiny
\begin{tblr}{colsep= 3pt,
             colspec={@{}r c |X[l]| X[l]| X[l]| X[l]| @{}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
             rowsep= 3pt
             }
              \toprule
 \textbf {Attributes} & \textbf Alfa} & \textbf {Bita} & \textbf {Gama} & \textbf {Unknown}\\ 
  \midrule
 
{Irrigation system}
& \cite {sharma2021iot, gomez2021agro, zhao2022design, thakur2020smart, talaviya2020implementation}
\cite {o2020site, jiaxing2018design, mahir2018soil, guillen2021high, patroo2019smart}
\cite {hemanth2019emerging, bodunde2019architectural, peng2019precision, mekonnen2018iot} 
\cite { yuanyuan2020research, lavanaya2018soil, difallah2018intelligent, hamdi2021internet, sambanasmart}
\cite{burton2018exploring, umar2021design, martinez2019application, garcia2018practical, huang2020design, kuchekar2021design, izaddoost2019enhanced, oussama2022fast, hu2018system}
\cite{karimi2018web, jia2019research, ningombam2020systematic, gao2021improved, john2019multi, rasooli2020applicability, subathra2019automated}
\cite{aydin2019multi, carlos2018wireless, borah2020low, alqahtani2022role}
\cite{kalam2020intelligent, yang2020design, jinbo2019agricultural}
\cite{dasgupta2020ai, za2021water, eraliev2021design, freeda2020iot, harun2019improved, samawismcsis}
\cite {dasig2020implementing, qiong2021design, kho2022development, wei2022zigbee, rajkumar2021smart, zhou2021design}, \cite{sai2021prototyping, keswani2019adapting, khalifeh2018simulation, li2020design, lijun2019analysis, liu2021automatic}, 
\cite{lou2020design, miao2019design, nagarajan2018wireless, abarananode, venkatra2020optimized}, 
\cite{singh2020wireless, prakash2020zigbee, rao2019design, ren2020design}, 
\cite{roy2020agrisens, freeda2020iot, samaras2018integrated, gao2018wireless, goumopoulos2018high}, 
\cite{sharma2020comparative, thaher2020cloud, maha2019smart, ramadhan2020smart, difallahsmart}, 
\cite{srivastava2020monitoring, bagaria2019smart, urkude2019agrisense, varalakshmi2019automatic, liu2018automatic, hamami2018integration, prabha2018design, chang2018agricultural, difallah2018smart}


& \cite{umar2021design, difallah2018smart, hamdi2021internet, karimi2018web, hamami2018integration, laha2022iot, rao2019design, kumar2020iot, muruganandam2021soil, barman2020solar, dasgupta2019smart, cheema2019plant, parra2018design, karar2021pilot, jaafar2019smart, bhanu2020iot, bachuwar2018monitoring, suriyachai2018effective, wan2019environment, bogdanoff2020ism, umarov2020micro, vijay2018improved, ndunagu2022development, thakur2018real, ortega2018remote, visconti2020iot, rajakumar2018iot, kamaruddin2019iot, alhasnawi2020internet, pernapati2018iot,  adam2019low, maja2018controlling, ali2021irrigation, velmurugan2020iot, garcia2020dronaway, lopez2020network, jimenez2021high, salam2020autonomous, bhattacharya2021smart, yousif2022experimental, krishnan2020self, zhao2017design, karaduman2020platform, garcia2019practical, burugari2022automated, bachuwar2018wsn, kumar2020internet, selvaraj2019automatic, alves2020precise, rajesh2020iot, kumar2022agriculture, rathinam2019modern,  muley2019internet, osroosh2018economical,  parameswari2018online, patil2020cognitive, patokar2018precision, parashar2021designing, podder2021iot,  pornillos2020smart, poyen2020prototype, premkumar2018iot, goap2018iot, madhumathi2020soil, kilaru2022automatic, sengupta2021farmfox, gloria2020water, visconti2020development, sagheer2020cloud, garcia2021deployment, siddiqui2021dimensioning, lloret2021wireless, shufian2021results, das2021smart, sharma2019smart, sharma2019smart, tiglao2020agrinex, gloria2019wsn} 

& 
\cite{di2019waters, fernandez2019proposal, lei2021key}

& \cite{sai2021prototyping,zhang2022lorawan,yang2020design,alves2020precise,fernandez2019proposal,gloria2020water,siddiqui2021dimensioning,arshad2022implementation,nigussie2020iot,xu2022uav,gupta2018agricultural,kodali2018lora,baldovino2018implementation,suwaid2019embedded,nyeki2020architecting,islam2018iot,shamshiri2021greenhouse,dupont2018open,trinh2018design,mohammed2019novel,silveira2021new,sharofidinov2021agriculture,valente2022lorawan,swain2021lora,borrero2020autonomous,dahane2022iot,jimenez2021new,zhang2020internet,boursianis2020smart,debauche2018irrigation,ahsan2021smart,nicolas2022energy,varshney2021expert,shaji2018raspberry,kaur2021iot,lyu2022design,madhumathi2022lora,narasimharao2022cloud,narasimharao2022cloud,olalla2022irrigation,nurellari2018practical,jiang2020investigation,khoa2019smart,emharraf2020intelligent,khalifeh2021framework,mya2020design,fraga2019design,singh2020leveraging,codeluppi2020lorafarm,froiz2020design,peddinti2020assessing,figorilli2021open,gloria2021sustainable,placidi2021monitoring,sanchez2021smart,briciu2022demonstrating,cao2021soil,chandrappa2022spatiotemporal,torre2020enhancing,kuntke2022lorawan, ekanayake2018advances} \\


\end{tblr}
\end{table}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{elsarticle-refs}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
Bita Gama Unknown
Irrigation system [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] [11, 12, 13, 14] [15, 16, 17, 18, 19] [20, 21, 22,
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28] [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35] [36, 37, 38, 39] [40, 41, 42] [43, 44, 45, 46,
47, 48] [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54], [55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], [61, 62, 63, 64, 65], [66, 67, 68, 69],
[70, 46, 71, 72, 73], [74, 75, 76, 77, 78], [79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87]
[21, 87, 18, 29, 84, 88, 68, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104,
105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123,
124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142,
143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 156, 157, 158]
[159, 160, 161]
[55, 162, 41, 130, 160, 148, 152, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174,
175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193,
193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211,
212, 213, 214, 215]
References
[1] R. P. Sharma, D. Ramesh, P. Pal, S. Tripathi, C. Kumar, Iot-enabled ieee 802.15. 4 wsn
monitoring infrastructure-driven fuzzy-logic-based crop pest prediction, IEEE Internet
of Things Journal 9 (4) (2021) 3037–3045.
[2] E. Gomez, J. E. Duque, A. J. Rojas, C. C. Jaik, J. A. Pertuz, Agro-smart caribe: Soil
moisture measurement system, in: Workshop on Engineering Applications, Springer,
2021, pp. 422–434.
[3] L. Zhao, Design of intelligent water-saving irrigation system based on internet of things,
Wireless Engineering and Technology 13 (3) (2022) 33–40.
[4] D. Thakur, Y. Kumar, S. Vijendra, Smart irrigation and intrusions detection in agri-
cultural fields using iot, Procedia Computer Science 167 (2020) 154–162.
[5] T. Talaviya, D. Shah, N. Patel, H. Yagnik, M. Shah, Implementation of artificial in-
telligence in agriculture for optimisation of irrigation and application of pesticides and
herbicides, Artificial Intelligence in Agriculture 4 (2020) 58–73.
[6] S. A. O’Shaughnessy, M. Kim, M. A. Andrade, P. D. Colaizzi, S. R. Evett, Site-specific
irrigation of grain sorghum using plant and soil water sensing feedback-texas high
plains, Agricultural Water Management 240 (2020) 106273.
[7] X. Jiaxing, G. Peng, W. Weixing, X. Xin, H. Guosheng, et al., Design of wireless
sensor network bidirectional nodes for intelligent monitoring system of micro-irrigation
in litchi orchards, IFAC-PapersOnLine 51 (17) (2018) 449–454.
```

I need cooperation to organize the references into a single table.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Zarko I need Your cooperation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not working with a `tblr` environment. For sure, there are no apparent problems when working with a `tabularx` environment instead.

The following screen shots shows lots of `?` (question mark) symbols simply because I don't have access to a bib file that contains the cited pieces.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LLLLL @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Attributes} & \textbf{Alfa} & \textbf{Bita} & \textbf{Gama} & \textbf{Unknown}\\ 
\midrule
Irrigation system
& 
\cite{sharma2021iot, gomez2021agro, zhao2022design, thakur2020smart, talaviya2020implementation}
\cite{o2020site, jiaxing2018design, mahir2018soil, guillen2021high, patroo2019smart}
\cite{hemanth2019emerging, bodunde2019architectural, peng2019precision, mekonnen2018iot} 
\cite{ yuanyuan2020research, lavanaya2018soil, difallah2018intelligent, hamdi2021internet, sambanasmart}
\cite{burton2018exploring, umar2021design, martinez2019application, garcia2018practical, huang2020design, kuchekar2021design, izaddoost2019enhanced, oussama2022fast, hu2018system}
\cite{karimi2018web, jia2019research, ningombam2020systematic, gao2021improved, john2019multi, rasooli2020applicability, subathra2019automated}
\cite{aydin2019multi, carlos2018wireless, borah2020low, alqahtani2022role}
\cite{kalam2020intelligent, yang2020design, jinbo2019agricultural}
\cite{dasgupta2020ai, za2021water, eraliev2021design, freeda2020iot, harun2019improved, samawismcsis}
\cite{dasig2020implementing, qiong2021design, kho2022development, wei2022zigbee, rajkumar2021smart, zhou2021design}  \cite{sai2021prototyping, keswani2019adapting, khalifeh2018simulation, li2020design, lijun2019analysis, liu2021automatic}  
\cite{lou2020design, miao2019design, nagarajan2018wireless, abarananode, venkatra2020optimized}  
\cite{singh2020wireless, prakash2020zigbee, rao2019design, ren2020design}  
\cite{roy2020agrisens, freeda2020iot, samaras2018integrated, gao2018wireless, goumopoulos2018high}  
\cite{sharma2020comparative, thaher2020cloud, maha2019smart, ramadhan2020smart, difallahsmart}  
\cite{srivastava2020monitoring, bagaria2019smart, urkude2019agrisense, varalakshmi2019automatic, liu2018automatic, hamami2018integration, prabha2018design, chang2018agricultural, difallah2018smart}
& 
\cite{umar2021design, difallah2018smart, hamdi2021internet, karimi2018web, hamami2018integration, laha2022iot, rao2019design, kumar2020iot, muruganandam2021soil, barman2020solar, dasgupta2019smart, cheema2019plant, parra2018design, karar2021pilot, jaafar2019smart, bhanu2020iot, bachuwar2018monitoring, suriyachai2018effective, wan2019environment, bogdanoff2020ism, umarov2020micro, vijay2018improved, ndunagu2022development, thakur2018real, ortega2018remote, visconti2020iot, rajakumar2018iot, kamaruddin2019iot, alhasnawi2020internet, pernapati2018iot,  adam2019low, maja2018controlling, ali2021irrigation, velmurugan2020iot, garcia2020dronaway, lopez2020network, jimenez2021high, salam2020autonomous, bhattacharya2021smart, yousif2022experimental, krishnan2020self, zhao2017design, karaduman2020platform, garcia2019practical, burugari2022automated, bachuwar2018wsn, kumar2020internet, selvaraj2019automatic, alves2020precise, rajesh2020iot, kumar2022agriculture, rathinam2019modern,  muley2019internet, osroosh2018economical,  parameswari2018online, patil2020cognitive, patokar2018precision, parashar2021designing, podder2021iot,  pornillos2020smart, poyen2020prototype, premkumar2018iot, goap2018iot, madhumathi2020soil, kilaru2022automatic, sengupta2021farmfox, gloria2020water, visconti2020development, sagheer2020cloud, garcia2021deployment, siddiqui2021dimensioning, lloret2021wireless, shufian2021results, das2021smart, sharma2019smart, sharma2019smart, tiglao2020agrinex, gloria2019wsn} 
& 
\cite{di2019waters, fernandez2019proposal, lei2021key}
& 
\cite{sai2021prototyping, zhang2022lorawan, yang2020design, alves2020precise, fernandez2019proposal, gloria2020water, siddiqui2021dimensioning, arshad2022implementation, nigussie2020iot, xu2022uav, gupta2018agricultural, kodali2018lora, baldovino2018implementation, suwaid2019embedded, nyeki2020architecting, islam2018iot, shamshiri2021greenhouse, dupont2018open, trinh2018design, mohammed2019novel, silveira2021new, sharofidinov2021agriculture, valente2022lorawan, swain2021lora, borrero2020autonomous, dahane2022iot, jimenez2021new, zhang2020internet, boursianis2020smart, debauche2018irrigation, ahsan2021smart, nicolas2022energy, varshney2021expert, shaji2018raspberry, kaur2021iot, lyu2022design, madhumathi2022lora, narasimharao2022cloud, narasimharao2022cloud, olalla2022irrigation, nurellari2018practical, jiang2020investigation, khoa2019smart, emharraf2020intelligent, khalifeh2021framework, mya2020design, fraga2019design, singh2020leveraging, codeluppi2020lorafarm, froiz2020design, peddinti2020assessing, figorilli2021open, gloria2021sustainable, placidi2021monitoring, sanchez2021smart, briciu2022demonstrating, cao2021soil, chandrappa2022spatiotemporal, torre2020enhancing, kuntke2022lorawan, ekanayake2018advances} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
 
\bibliography{elsarticle-refs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thank You very much @Mico

Answer (score 1):

Your table has two errors:

- table has five column, but you specifies six, from which first two not enables to break text in several lines. Consequently first column with cites has not line breaks and last column is not used.
- In column headers you lost one `{`, so you get error

```
! Argument of \environment tblr  has an extra }.
```

After correction of column specification, reformat the column headers as enable `tabularray` package and eliminate vertical rules, I got the following (desired) result:

[image]

It is not clear,

- how many rows has your table
- why in the first row are many citation groups (some of them are separated by commas)

  - does each of them should be separated by commas (as is done in above in MWE below), or
  - should each citation group start in new line?

So far I managed your MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
%% for removing the footer
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  %\let\@oddfoot\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\usepackage{afterpage,lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum, pdflscape}

\usepackage{array, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} X[0.6,l] X[l] X[l] X[0.4,l] X[l] @{}},
             row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries, c},
             rowsep= 3pt
             }
    \toprule
Attributes  & Alfa  & Beta  & Gama  & Unknown   \\
    \midrule
Irrigation system
    &   \cite {sharma2021iot, gomez2021agro, zhao2022design, thakur2020smart, talaviya2020implementation},    
        \cite {o2020site, jiaxing2018design, mahir2018soil, guillen2021high, patroo2019smart},
        \cite {hemanth2019emerging, bodunde2019architectural, peng2019precision, mekonnen2018iot},
        \cite { yuanyuan2020research, lavanaya2018soil, difallah2018intelligent, hamdi2021internet, sambanasmart},
        \cite{burton2018exploring, umar2021design, martinez2019application, garcia2018practical, huang2020design, 
              kuchekar2021design, izaddoost2019enhanced, oussama2022fast, hu2018system},
        \cite{karimi2018web, jia2019research, ningombam2020systematic, gao2021improved, john2019multi, rasooli2020applicability, 
               subathra2019automated},
        \cite{aydin2019multi, carlos2018wireless, borah2020low, alqahtani2022role},
        \cite{kalam2020intelligent, yang2020design, jinbo2019agricultural},
        \cite{dasgupta2020ai, za2021water, eraliev2021design, freeda2020iot, harun2019improved, samawismcsis},
        \cite {dasig2020implementing, qiong2021design, kho2022development, wei2022zigbee, rajkumar2021smart, zhou2021design}, 
        \cite{sai2021prototyping, keswani2019adapting, khalifeh2018simulation, li2020design, lijun2019analysis, liu2021automatic},
        \cite{lou2020design, miao2019design, nagarajan2018wireless, abarananode, venkatra2020optimized},
        \cite{singh2020wireless, prakash2020zigbee, rao2019design, ren2020design},
        \cite{roy2020agrisens, freeda2020iot, samaras2018integrated, gao2018wireless, goumopoulos2018high},
        \cite{sharma2020comparative, thaher2020cloud, maha2019smart, ramadhan2020smart, difallahsmart},
        \cite{srivastava2020monitoring, bagaria2019smart, urkude2019agrisense, varalakshmi2019automatic, liu2018automatic, 
              hamami2018integration, prabha2018design, chang2018agricultural, difallah2018smart}
        &   \cite{umar2021design, difallah2018smart, hamdi2021internet, karimi2018web, hamami2018integration, laha2022iot, 
                  rao2019design, kumar2020iot, muruganandam2021soil, barman2020solar, dasgupta2019smart, cheema2019plant, 
                  parra2018design, karar2021pilot, jaafar2019smart, bhanu2020iot, bachuwar2018monitoring, suriyachai2018effective, 
                  wan2019environment, bogdanoff2020ism, umarov2020micro, vijay2018improved, ndunagu2022development, thakur2018real, 
                  ortega2018remote, visconti2020iot, rajakumar2018iot, kamaruddin2019iot, alhasnawi2020internet, pernapati2018iot,  
                  adam2019low, maja2018controlling, ali2021irrigation, velmurugan2020iot, garcia2020dronaway, lopez2020network, 
                  jimenez2021high, salam2020autonomous, bhattacharya2021smart, yousif2022experimental, krishnan2020self, zhao2017design, 
                  karaduman2020platform, garcia2019practical, burugari2022automated, bachuwar2018wsn, kumar2020internet, 
                  selvaraj2019automatic, alves2020precise, rajesh2020iot, kumar2022agriculture, rathinam2019modern,  muley2019internet, 
                  osroosh2018economical,  parameswari2018online, patil2020cognitive, patokar2018precision, parashar2021designing, 
                  podder2021iot,  pornillos2020smart, poyen2020prototype, premkumar2018iot, goap2018iot, madhumathi2020soil, 
                  kilaru2022automatic, sengupta2021farmfox, gloria2020water, visconti2020development, sagheer2020cloud, garcia2021deployment, 
                  siddiqui2021dimensioning, lloret2021wireless, shufian2021results, das2021smart, sharma2019smart, sharma2019smart, 
                  tiglao2020agrinex, gloria2019wsn}
            &   \cite{di2019waters, fernandez2019proposal, lei2021key}
                &   \cite{sai2021prototyping, zhang2022lorawan, yang2020design, alves2020precise, fernandez2019proposal, gloria2020water,
                          siddiqui2021dimensioning, arshad2022implementation, nigussie2020iot, xu2022uav, gupta2018agricultural,
                          kodali2018lora, baldovino2018implementation, suwaid2019embedded, nyeki2020architecting, islam2018iot,
                          shamshiri2021greenhouse, dupont2018open, trinh2018design, mohammed2019novel, silveira2021new, sharofidinov2021agriculture,
                          valente2022lorawan, swain2021lora, borrero2020autonomous, dahane2022iot, jimenez2021new, zhang2020internet,
                          boursianis2020smart, debauche2018irrigation, ahsan2021smart, nicolas2022energy, varshney2021expert, shaji2018raspberry,
                          kaur2021iot, lyu2022design, madhumathi2022lora, narasimharao2022cloud, narasimharao2022cloud, 
                          olalla2022irrigation, nurellari2018practical, jiang2020investigation, khoa2019smart, emharraf2020intelligent,
                          khalifeh2021framework, mya2020design, fraga2019design, singh2020leveraging, codeluppi2020lorafarm, froiz2020design,
                          peddinti2020assessing, figorilli2021open, gloria2021sustainable, placidi2021monitoring,sanchez2021smart,
                          briciu2022demonstrating, cao2021soil, chandrappa2022spatiotemporal, torre2020enhancing, kuntke2022lorawan, 
                          ekanayake2018advances} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{elsarticle-refs}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: In document preamble I remove all duplicate loaded packages and a bit reorganised it.